# GooglePlacesAutocomplete moves searchbar up when active

Tags: swift, swift3, google-places

Currently I followed those steps to implement an autocomplete search bar with Google Places.

> https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_ui_control

So far so good, it works but when i click on the search bar it moves down, which is what i dont want.

From: 
[image]

To (when clicked):

[image]

My current code is quite the same as in the tutorial (I also tried the bugfix after it, doesnt work)

```
var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
    var searchController: UISearchController?
    var resultView: UITextView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Event-Filter";

        resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

        let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 45.0))

        subView.addSubview((searchController?.searchBar)!)
        view.addSubview(subView)
        searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "Enter a specific place!";

        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
        // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Handle User Selection

    func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        searchController?.isActive = false
        searchController?.searchBar.text = place.formattedAddress;
        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress ?? "not found")")
        print("Place lat:" + String(place.coordinate.latitude))

    }

    func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                           didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
        let backend = BackendService()
        backend.alert(view: self, message: error.localizedDescription, title: "Something went wrong!")
    }

    // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }
```

Comment: Do you fix this problem?

Comment: It worked with the answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I had the same problem and I made it work correctly by using the following line of code:

```
definesPresentationContext = false
```

I tested it quite a lot and it is working perfectly for me.

Comment: @reza_khalafi Still working for me... even tho someone apparently downvoted the answer.